# require paths in node not working anymore, but used to work -- code all being the same

Tags: node.js

I have requires that look like

```
var config = require('config');
```

That works on my Linux server, and that used to work on my Windows PC as well. Now I have to make it look like

```
var config = require('./config');
```

Why is that? Is there a setting that can make it work again without having to edit all the files?

Example of error I get:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'models/user'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\myApp\REST_API\rest.js:1:3
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\myApp\REST_API> node .\app.js
```

Comment: That error doesn't seem to match up with the problem you describe.  In the original example, if you had `var config = require('config');` and there was no `config` module available, you should see an error like `Error: Cannot find module 'config'`.  The `Error: Cannot find module 'models/user'` must be from somewhere else?

Comment: Hi Dylants, yes -- it's just another "require" I have that's also broken. (after I edited config to make it look like ./config, then it showed the next "wrong" path).

Comment: It has to do with NODE_PATH. I must find out how to use it under Windows. On Linux it's using something like `export NODE_PATH=.`

Comment: I have to admit, I hadn't heard of `NODE_PATH` until now ([here's the current documentation on it](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders)). That being said, the documentation itself recommends against using it, and if someone was to use your project they would hit these errors. Wouldn't it be best just to specify the path if it's a local file rather than a module?

Answer (score 0):

You use
`var config = require('config');` for modules that are in the node_modules folder, which are installed when you use `npm install`.

You use `var config = require('./config');` for your own modules, in this case, for the module that you wrote which is `models/user`.